# How do I console.log only the highestRated rating and the Movie-title of highestRated rating

Tags: javascript, function, console.log, abstraction

I have been trying to out only the rating and title of the movie but when consolelog highestRated
I keep on getting the full object.
How do I console.log only the highestRated rating and the Movie-title of highestRated rating

sample output;

highest rated : Joker (10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get highestRated rating and highestRated movieTitle

```
// movieTitle
console.log(highestRated.movieTitle);
// rating
console.log(highestRated.rating);

// Output highest rated: Joker(10)
console.log(`highest rated : ${highestRated.movieTitle} (${highestRated.rating})`);
```